# Cannot save notebooks on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a problem with saving my notebook in Vertex AI Workbench. This problem happened the second time today. I've really lost a **lot** of work in my notebook. Everything was fine, I saved the notebook as usual. However, after restarting the notebook, all my work had disappeared! It is really surprising that a lot of users [complaining](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/259298104) about this problem on the platform ([another example](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/246448042)). Unfortunately, no one could find a solution?

My question: How I can assure that my notebook is saved when working on GCP Vertex AI? The notebook is linked to my github account. (Unfortunately, the changes were not pushed into repository.)

Comment: Can you provide the image version? We had an issue few months ago which is fixed in the latest version. Issue: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/release-notes#September_20_2022

Comment: I have similar problems lasting over and over. I save frequently, do regular copies within the workbench and download notebooks (beyond commiting to repos)... One shall consider workbenches as being unsafe...

Comment: @gogasca I don't use workbench anymore and don't have access neither... I've lost a lot of time and effort because of this problem...

Comment: Same problem here. Saving doesn't work for High-GPU A100 40gb notebook